# Como creo una matriz en C con mas de 294 elementos , ya que esta se cae y da :RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 469ms) en NeatBeans

Tags: c, fórmulas-de-matriz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

double performancecounter_diff(LARGE_INTEGER *a, LARGE_INTEGER *b){
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
return (double)(a->QuadPart - b->QuadPart) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
}

void main() {
int a ;
a=294;
multiplicacionM(a);
}

void multiplicacionM(int n){
long int a[n][n];
long int b[n][n];
long int i=0;
long int j=0;
long int k=0;
long int  temporal;


printf("Llegue 3");
for( i=0;i<n;i++){
    for ( j=0;j<n;j++){
        a[i][j]=rand()%1000;
        b[i][j]=rand()%1000;
    }
}

long int matriz [n][n];


for( i=0;i<n;i++){
    for ( j=0;j<n;j++){
        matriz[i][j]=0;
    }
 }

    //LARGE_INTEGER t_ini, t_fin;
 //double secs;

 //QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_ini);

 for( i=0;i<n;i++){
     for ( j=0;j<n;j++){
                temporal = 0 ;
        for( k=0;k<n;k++){
                        temporal+= a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            matriz[i][j] =temporal;
        }
     }
   }
  //QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_fin);

   //secs = performancecounter_diff(&t_fin, &t_ini);
   //printf("%.16g milisegundos\n", secs * 1000.0);

     printf("Termine");

    }
```

Comment: Como bien mencionan ya en respuesta por "Trauma" estas gastando mucha memoria; si a fin de cuenta los valores de A y B los multiplicaras para colocarlos en "matriz" con los bucles para  "i" y "j" hacia "matriz[i[j]= (rand()%1000) * (rand()%1000)" bastara; estas creando 3 matrices bidimensionales

Answer (score 2):

Estás creando 3 matrices, cada una de ellas de `294 * 294 = 86436`, lo que nos da un total de `259308` elementos; si cada elemento ocupa 4 *bytes*, tenemos `1037232` *bytes* (como mínimo) **ocupados en la pila**.

Para realizar lo que quieres, la solución es utilizar *memoria dinámica*, llamando a `malloc( )` o `calloc( )` para **asignar memoria**, y luego llamando a `free( )` para **liberarla**:

```
void multiplicacionM( int n ){
  size_t total = n * n; // Total de elementos necesarios.
  long int *a = malloc( total * sizeof( long ) );
  long int *b = malloc( total * sizeof( long ) );
  // Ahora usamos 'calloc( )', para no hacernos monótonos :-)
  long int *matriz = calloc( total, sizeof( long ) );
  long int i;
  long int  temporal;

  printf( "Llegue 3\n" );

  // Inicializamos 'a' y 'b' con valores aleatorios.
  for( i = 0; i < total; ++i ) {
    a[i] = rand( ) % 1000;
    b[i] = rand( ) % 1000;
  }

  // Inicializamos 'matriz' con 0.
  for( i = 0; i < total; ++i )
    matriz[i] = 0;

  // También podríamos hacer
  // memset( matriz, 0, sizeof( long ) * total );

  for( i = 0; i < total; ++i ) {
    temporal = a[i] * b[i];
    matriz[i] = temporal;
  }

  printf("Terminé\n");

  // ¡ Que no se nos olvide liberar la memoria !
  free( a );
  free( b );
  free( matriz );
}
```

Observa que, en lugar de *matrices[X][Y]*, utilizo una *matriz[X]*. Dado los cálculos que quieres hacer, es *mucho mas simple*, y funciona porque, en C, la posición en memoria de los elementos de una `matriz[3][3]`

> [1] [2] [3]
>     [4] [5] [6]
>     [7] [8] [9]

es, realmente, **la misma** que la posición en memoria de los elementos en una matriz[3*3]:

> [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9]

Tal vez no sea tan claro, pero funciona **exactamente igual** en ambas formas.

Comment: Un apunte: VLA (Variable Length Array) **si** es legal en C. Donde no es legal es en C++.

Comment: @eferion Como siempre, acertado. Corregido. Que no estoy muy *centrado* últimamente :-(